# SQL Server stored procedure naming

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have started naming our stored procedures as `[16_TestStoredProc]`. Are there any implications naming a stored procedure like this?

I am not going to explain why we are doing this. It is not that I have issues with this, but would to any implications.

Comment: Thanks for testing for all of us all the tools that break with unquoted names :)

Comment: Thanks community for not bringing down this question saying *Not a real question* . I am sure this will help future readers to understand the implications of using different naming conventions.

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you're doing this.

Comment: I recommend naming your stored procedures using a "NounVerb" pattern.  Examples are "EmployeeGetAll" and "EmployeeInsert".  This keeps all of your related stored procedures sorted together.

Comment: That doesn't seem that it would make for a very usable solution, for your programmers or for long-term maintenance.  I generally go with a VerbNoun pattern - GetEmployee, e.g. - which doesn't keep all of the Employee procedures together as NounVerb does, but it is much more intuitive.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet, I find that when doing maintenance, I'm more interested in all stored procedures that involve Employees, than all that involve the "Get" operation.  I don't often run into situations where I need to look at all stored procedures that have select statements in them.  A tool like ApexSearch that allows you to search the text of stored procedures renders this moot however.  Still I like to keep things sorted by what they're acting on rather than what action they're doing.

Comment: Ahh, see, I'm looking at it from the perspective of actually *using* the stored procedures, where you know you're getting something rather than saving it, for example. It makes it simpler to consume, and to know you're actually doing what you're wanting to do, particularly with autocomplete & all that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are no *technical* issues with this.

It isn't going to make any difference to SQL Server.

From a usability point of view identifier names that begin with a number must always be quoted so

```
exec some_schema.16_TestStoredProc
```

would not be valid and you must always use

```
exec some_schema.[16_TestStoredProc]
```

Also when viewing the stored procedures alphabetically sorted - e.g. in Object explorer this prefix may well not be helpful in trying to find a stored procedure and as they are ordered lexicographically it may be somewhat inconvenient that `18_TestStoredProc` precedes `2_TestStoredProc`.

> I am not going to explain why we are doing this

Well perhaps you have good reasons. As you aren't going to share them it isn't possible for us to comment on them.